# How to wait for android Volley response (synchronously)?

Tags: java, android, networking, android-asynctask, android-volley

I am trying to generate room codes in my application and I wanted to be able to check the database to ensure that any room code generated is unique.
To do this I need to make an asynchronous volley request and wait for its response. I first tried using RequestFuture, but I could not run `future.get()` from the main thread. Then I tried using a callback...

```
public interface DataCallback {
    void onSuccess(String result);
    String getResponse();
}
```

where `callback.getResponse()` was supposed to return the volley response, but that all behaved asynchronously too (flow of execution didn't wait for the callback).
I've also tried executing the future from within an AsyncTask...

```
private class GenerateRoomCode extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // Generate random string
        RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, future, future);
        NetworkController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        try {
            Log.d("Db", "" + future.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Db", "" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return roomCode;
    }
}
```

But it also times out and crashes the application.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: what is the error when the application crashes?

Comment: The application just times out and closes (without an error)

Comment: in the android studio logcat error might be displayed what is the error check that when the application crashes

Comment: What is inside of NetworkController? For what exactly do you need the AsyncTask reference in your NetworkController?

Comment: @aditya1508, logcat never shows an error. It seems like the main thread is getting blocked indefinitely even though the `future.get()` call is in an AsyncTask.

Comment: @TimS. The NetworkController just a singleton request queue manager.